# Return Cell Address/Row After Countif

Tags: excel, vba, cell

I would like to ask for help regarding getting the cell address or row once the countif criteria is met. I feel like I am just missing something simple.

Here is a chunk of what I have so far:

```
    Wb2.Activate
    Wb2.Sheets.Add(After:=Wb2.Sheets(Wb2.Sheets.Count)).Name = "Report"
    With Wb2.Sheets("From")
        Set myRange = .Range("F2:G" & lastRow)
    End With

    With Wb2.Sheets("Weekly_Stat")
        Set forComp = Wb2.Sheets("Weekly_Stat").Range("D2:E" & lastRow2)
    End With

    Sheets("From").Activate

    For Each item In myRange.Rows
        With item 
            .Select
            myCount = item.Row
            myBool = False
            foundIt = Application.CountIfs(forComp.Columns(1), .Cells(1).Value, forComp.Columns(2), .Cells(2).Value)
            If foundIt Then myBool = True
                If myBool = True Then
                    myStr = forComp.Row
                    Wb2.Sheets("Report").Cells(myCount, 10).Value = "Found"
                    MsgBox myStr
                Else
                    Wb2.Sheets("Report").Cells(myCount, 10).Value = "Not Found"
                End If
        End With
    Next item
```

In the code, I am trying to get the row of item found in forComp, but I am failing miserably.

I am wondering how I can get the row number of the match found in "Weekly_Stat".

Currently, I am only able to determine if the data from "From" sheet are found in "Weekly_Stat". I placed a column for "Found" and "Not Found" in a new "Report" sheet.

What I wanted to do is:

- Check if data is found in Weekly_Stat, place results in Report (done)
- After finding that data exist in Weekly_Stat, I need to get the address/row
- I will be using the row/address to get another data from the next columns in same row from the Weekly_Stat.

I tried searching about my dilemma, but I am unable to find solutions. I might probably be using the wrong keywords to search, so my apologies in advance if this has already been asked. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks very much.

Comment: It looks like you want to return the row number for a two column match. There are easier ways to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to see exactly what you're trying to do, but it seems as if you want to take each value in a column of one sheet and see if that value exists in the column of another sheet. If this is correct, then I'm not convinced your methodology is the best way to go.

Typically, we would iterate one column and then iterate a second to test for each matche, and this will give us the index of the found rows. Yes, it's true that the Excel functions that take a `Range` as a parameter will run an internal iteration, but it's difficult to control (and debug) your searches that way, especially if you are just starting out in VBA.

It's a lot quicker (and, in my view, easier) to read your cell values into arrays and loop through those. If you were interested in taking that route, then your code could look something like the skeleton code below. Note: you'll need to adjust all of your range definitions and qualifiers to suit your own Workbooks, sheets and needs.

There are even quicker, but more complicated, ways of achieving your task, especially if the data is unique, but this offers some simple array loops to get you going.

```
Dim fromVals As Variant, weekVals As Variant
Dim reportVals() As Variant
Dim r1 As Long, r2 As Long
Dim found As Boolean

'Read ranges into arrays for the two sheets.
'Note: define your ranges to suit.
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("From")
    fromVals = .Range(.Cells(2, "F"), _
               .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp)) _
               .Resize(, 2).Value2
End With

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Weekly_Stat")
    weekVals = .Range(.Cells(2, "D"), _
               .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)) _
               .Resize(, 2).Value2
End With

'Dimension the output array.
'Note: example uses num of rows in "From" sheet and 2 columns.
ReDim reportVals(1 To UBound(fromVals, 1), 1 To 2)

'Loop through "From array2 to acquire each value.
For r1 = 1 To UBound(fromVals, 1)
    found = False 'sets the found flag each iteration
    'Loop through "Week" array to look for match with "From" value.
    For r2 = 1 To UBound(weekVals, 1)
        If weekVals(r2, 1) = fromVals(r1, 1) Then
            'We've found a match
            reportVals(r1, 1) = "Found" 'writes found in same row index as "From" array
            reportVals(r1, 2) = weekVals(r2, 2) 'writes value from "G" column of "week" array
            found = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If Not found Then reportVals(r1, 1) = "Not found"
Next

'Writes report array to sheet.
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report").Cells(2, 10) _
    .Resize(UBound(reportVals, 1), UBound(reportVals, 2)) _
    .Value = reportVals
```

Comment: Thank you very much for a really clear explanation. You are correct that it is hard to manipulate searches via the excel functions. I like your idea of using variable arrays for the searches. This is really helpful. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If we were to find the matching row using formula, we would write this array formula at row 2 of the report:

```
=MATCH(1,(Weekly_Stat!D:D=From!F2)*(Weekly_Stat!E:E=From!G2),0)  ' Ctrl+Shift+Enter
```

And then we fill down the column. To automate the process with VBA, we can do it like this (replaces all your code from the first to the last line, only supposes that `lastRow` was computed correctly):

```
 With Wb2.Sheets.Add(After:=Wb2.Sheets(Wb2.Sheets.count))
   .name = "Report"
   .Range("J2").FormulaArray = _
      "=MATCH(1,(Weekly_Stat!D:D=From!F2)*(Weekly_Stat!E:E=From!G2),0)"
   .Range("J2:J" & lastrow).FillDown
 End With
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. The code is neat and straightforward. I am happy to learn about the .FillDown. Really appreciate your help!